# Calling CHKDSK Python

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

For research purposes I have been trying to learn the use of ctypes in order to create an application for media driver management. Using fmifs.dll I was able to implement the format and setlabel functions, however I cannot seem to implement chkdsk despite the documentation I have showing I have my parameters correct.

```
CB_FUNC = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int, c_void_p)
FileManager = windll.LoadLibrary("fmifs.dll")

def Callback(command, modifier, arg):
     print(command)
     return 1

def check_disk(Drive, Format):
     FileManager.ChkdskEx(c_wchar_p(Drive), c_wchar_p(Format),
     True, False,False, False,
     c_void_p(0), c_void_p(0), CB_FUNC(Callback))

check_disk('I:\\', 'FAT32')
```

The compiler gives me an error message saying "Exception: Access violation reading 0x00000000", so if anyone knows the proper way of implementing this, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Where is the documentation? Don't develop this in Python. Do it in C++ using the official header files. That way you remove your ctypes interop code as a possible source of errors. Once you know how to call the function from C++, port to ctypes.

Comment: When you define CB_FUNC, the callback takes four parameters, but it actually takes three. Could you try using the proper callback signature?

Comment: The only helpful source I could find is here: [link](http://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d85/fmifs_8h.html).

Also I the way CB_FUNC is defined is correct, both chkdsk and format use the same parameters for their callback methods and it works for format. Even then, I have tried fiddling with the number of parameters and nothing works.

Comment: Is the problem in your interop, or in the arguments you pass to the function? If you don't know the answer to that with 100% certainty, switch to C++ to remove interop from the candidates for error.

Comment: I tried also to do some "bindings" on that function, but I got the same error. Looking at the disassembled function (tested on Windows 10) it became obvious that the function has changed a lot... It now takes only 5 args, the 4th arg is a now a pointer (this is why you have a dereferenced pointer at 0/NULL) , and other subtle changes. It shouldn't that hard to bind to it now, but the risk is still the same: undocumented functions can change without further notice. I suggest sticking to a documented way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh, it's not even documented, and so doesn't have a header file. Well, all bets are off then!!

Comment: Using WMI, [`MSFT_Volume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830604) (Windows 8+) has a `Repair` method, and [Win32_Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515) has a `Chkdsk` method. Your research could switch to using WMI in Python. [PyMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMI) looks interesting.